# Openshift cluster autoscaler does not remove GPU nodes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

We see that cluster autoscaler as described here: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/machine_management/applying-autoscaling.html scale up when it sees pending GPU pods but does not scale down when a workload is completed and pods are removed. any clue what could be stopping the scale-down, I have made sure that we have enabled scaledown in our OpenShift 4.9 setup

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether all of the following conditions are false in your cluster for the node which needs to be removed by autoscaler

If the following types of pods are present on a node, the cluster autoscaler will not remove the node:

Pods with restrictive pod disruption budgets (PDBs).

Kube-system pods that do not run on the node by default.

Kube-system pods that do not have a PDB or have a PDB that is too restrictive.

Pods that are not backed by a controller object such as a deployment, replica set, or stateful set.

Pods with local storage.

Pods that cannot be moved elsewhere because of a lack of resources, incompatible node selectors or affinity, matching anti-affinity, and so on.

Unless they also have a "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "true" annotation, pods that have a "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "false" annotation.

Comment: Figured out the issue the resource section was having errors. I did not specify GPU req in both requests and limits section.

Comment: are you sure ?  because not specifying the requests & limits put the container/pod  in lowest QoS which is BestEffort and hence these pods should be the first to go down in case of resource crunch or node termination.

Comment: I mean I did not specify GPU requirement in the resources section of the yaml and I was asking for a GPU node. I think that confused the CA somehow.

Comment: That makes sense